# Android Java How to connect IP camera inside activity 

Tags: java, android, android-activity, connection, ip-camera

I am looking for any tip or guidance to develop an application like cam viewer. So i will see the live videos on my android application by using IP address and port.

I searched this question but i could not find proper answer anywhere so please help me in this regard. I need to create an android application with this feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've looked into this a little, and I think most apps are written specifically to the camera model.  There doesn't seem to be any standard for IP cams.

I would have an adapter for each camera model.  Investigate the specific model to find the URL to the video by looking at the web page created by the camera's web server.

Comment: Thanks for the reply , yes the ip camera that was given to me has a URL and after following your advice i  have open the html code of the url. Then i finally found the URL that give every time a new image. So it means i have to create the image player by myself...

Comment: Hi Steve , how can i find the URL for each camera model and diffrent company... please advice me

Answer (score 1):

Many IP cams provide access to the 'video' as images (usually in jpg format) others allow you to access the stream of bytes and others have both options. There are some cams that provide an sdk so you can access the video and control them remotely through http calls. As @Steve H. suggests its a good idea to create an adapter for each model. If the cam allows you to access the video as a sequence of images then you can just read the images and display them using an ImageView and update it every *n* milliseconds.

Comment: you were 100% correct i found the url and it gave me the image everytime when i refresh it. So it means the android application that i need to create must have this kind of url and as you said with every milliseconds i have to update it inside the activity.... Thanks i will do that now. I will vote you for it...